# While loop not taking in data after the first loop

Tags: c

I am having a bit of a problem with my code. What I'm doing here is basically using ASCII for input validation, and it works fine without the while loop, but if I use the while loop it will run once perfectly, but when it reaches back to the top of the code it stop working meaning it assumes everything is invalid input.

```
    void menu()
            {
                char userInput[10] = {0};
                int asciiCode[10];
                int i;
                int countZero = 0;
                int storeUserOption;

                while (storeUserOption !=1 && storeUserOption !=2 && storeUserOption !=0)
{

                printf("\nPlease enter any of the following options:\n");
                printf("\nEnter winning number (w)\n");
                printf("\nEnter ticket numbers (t)\n");
                printf("\nquit (q)\n");
                printf("\n>: ");

               fgets(userInput, 10, stdin);

                /*It converts whatever I type in asciiData, and see if there's left over data*/
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    asciiCode[i] = userInput[i];
                    if (asciiCode[i] == 0)
                    {
                        countZero++;
                    }
                }


            /*It takes left over data and subtracts it by 10 to reSize it*/
                int reSize = (10 - countZero);

         /*It checks to see if you enetered anything more than 2 element if so it will input
            invalid input. For example can input dd, but can't input asdadasdasd*/
                if (reSize > 2)
                {
                    printf("Invalid Input1.");
                }

           /*If there's two elements left inside the array*/
                else if (reSize  == 2)
                    {
                        if (asciiCode[0] == 119)
                        {
                            printf("You have entered w");
                            storeUserOption = 1;
                        }

                        else if (asciiCode[0] == 116)
                        {
                           printf("You have entered t");
                            storeUserOption = 2;
                        }

                        else if (asciiCode[0] == 113)
                        {
                             printf("You have entered q");
                              storeUserOption = 0;
                        }

                        else{
                             printf("Invalid Input.");

                        }
                }
}

            }
```

Comment: Not seeing a `while` loop...

Comment: well me either. there is no `while` loop in your code. did you post the correct code snippet ?

Comment: Please post the code with your while loop in it.

Comment: My bad forgot to include it. Thank you.

Comment: Added the while loop!

Comment: I am surprised if this code enters `while` loop even once. `storeUserOption` is not initialized. Oh I see. Since `storeUserOption` is garbage initially it DOES enter the loop. But I am confident you dont want such behavior.

Comment: Sorry my compiler isn't the best. You are absolutely right! I need to initialized it

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart your variables at the beginning of the while loop.

```
int storeUserOption = 100; // needs to be something so it enters your while loop

While( ... ) {
                char userInput[10] = {0};
                int asciiCode[10];
                int i;
                int countZero = 0;



}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! Was it because it was keeping data from the initial run, and kept using it?

Comment: Yep that is why. It is always good practice to reset your variables at the beginning of a `while` loop, unless of course you need them to maintain certain state within every iteration.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you very much :) I am surprise haven't tried this approach, guess not thinking straight with so many projects due..